# sqlite3: Preserve table names in query with JOIN

Tags: python, sqlite

I want to execute a SQL query with a JOIN where I can propagate the table aliases into the resulting dictionary keys. For example, I may have a query

```
query = """
        SELECT t1.col1,t2.col1,t2.col2 
        FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2
        ON t1.col0=t2.col0
        """
```

and I want the output to maintain the t1, t2 aliases, since I have duplicate column names (col1). I would run

```
con = sqlite3.connect(dbpath, isolation_level=None, detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES)

def dict_factory(cursor, row):
    d = {}
    for idx,col in enumerate(cursor.description): d[col[0]] = row[idx]
    return d

db.dict = con.cursor()
db.dict.row_factory = dict_factory
result = db.dict.execute(query).fetchone()
```

But this overwrites the `col1` value. How can I have it return, say,

```
{'t1.col1':123, 't2.col1':234, 't2.col2':345}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/column_name.html) says:

> The name of a result column is the value of the "AS" clause for that column, if there is an AS clause. If there is no AS clause then the name of the column is unspecified and may change from one release of SQLite to the next.

So you have to do:

```sql
SELECT t1.col1 AS "t1.col1", t2.col1 AS "t2.col1", ...
```